# Don't get a 404 response for invalid id

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am getting the following error when setting up my workoutId param:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5fb02bd8b61abc02" at path "_id" for model "Workout"

I'm able to successfully make a GET request if the workoutId exists but when I try with an id that doesn't exist, it should give me a 404 response but it doesn't. Is there something that I'm missing?

```
workoutsRouter.param('workoutId', async (req, res, next, workoutId) => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://nalanart:hidingpassword@cluster0.2iplh.mongodb.net/workout-app-db?retryWrites=true&w=majority', 
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

    const workout = await Workout.findById(workoutId).exec()

    if(Object.keys(workout).length === 0) {
      res.sendStatus(404)
    } else {
      req.workout = workout
      next()
    }

  } catch(error) {
    throw error
  }
  
})
```

Comment: Add `res.sendStatus(404)` into catch block

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question is as simple as add `res.sendStatus(404)` into catch block.

However, is important to know what code return.

**404** is for a value not found. So, when the query is done but not return any document, you can send `404`. But if the query fails, a better option is send other status code.

In this case **400** code could be a better option. According to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) (and many other, this is an standar):

> 400 Bad Request: The server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax.